# ¿Es posible en PHP poner un texto en una determinada posición de una cadena?

Tags: php, string

Estoy creando contenido desde PHP para enviarlo a una aplicación Android.

Actualmente la App está habilitada para recibir ese contenido y presentarlo en un `TextView` spanned.

Por el momento tengo que recurrir a etiquetas algo rudimentarias como `font`, `small`, etc. porque no será hasta una próxima actualización de la App cuando trabajaré el `TextView` de forma que pueda presentar texto usando reglas CSS.

El hecho es que desde PHP, para no escribir tanto código como:

```
$strTextoConRojo='<font color="red">Lorem ipsum</font>';
$strTextoEnPequeno='<small>Lorem ipsum</small>';
```

He creado variables así:

#### En rojo:

```
$color="red";
$cssFont_="<font color=\"$color\">";
$_cssFont='</font>';
$strTextoEnRojo="$cssFont_ Lorem ipsum ... $_cssFont";
echo $strTextoEnRojo;
```

***Salida***:

```
<font color="red"> Lorem ipsum ... </font>
```

#### En pequeño:

```
$cssSmall_="<small>";
$_cssSmall="</small>";

$strTextoEnSmall="$cssSmall_ Lorem ipsum ... $_cssSmall";
echo $strTextoEnSmall;
```

***Salida:***

```
<small> Lorem ipsum ... </small>
```

Así funciona, pero quiero llegar a una simplificación mayor.

Lo que quiero saber es si hay alguna forma de poner texto dinámico entre dos cadenas, de forma que pueda crear mis elementos de apertura y cierre y poner en medio cualquier cadena.

Algo así:

```
$cssSmall="<small>?</small>";
```

Y que pueda, en diversas partes partes del programa, colocar cualquier texto en lugar de `?` para obtener ese texto entre las dos etiquetas.  ¿Cómo podría lograrlo?

Comment: Podrias hacer uso de [str_ireplace](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-ireplace.php),o hacerte tu propia funcion con ayuda de esa funcion.

Comment: Y si colocas una variable entre comillas dobles ? es sabido que las comillas dobles en php soportan variables por lo que podria funcionar, `$cssSmall="<small>$mi_contenido</small>";`

Comment: @Shassain en efecto, eso podría ser, algo como: `$cssSmall="<small>?</small>";
$textoEnSmall = str_ireplace("?", "Lorem ipsum...", $cssSmall);` ...

Comment: @YoAlbert pero ¿cómo simplificaría en ese caso, cómo sustituyo `$mi_contenido` cada vez que requiera un texto rodeado de `<small>...texto...</small>`?

Comment: se me ocurrio algo como esto checalo: https://pastebin.com/iysatjS1

Comment: en resumen cree una funcion donde recibe como parametro el texto deseado y retorna el tag completo... y lo imprime con htmlspecialchars para mostrar el tag html

Comment: y el output seria: <font color="red">prueba de texto</font>

Comment: Gracias @Tegito123 pero la función está limitada al color rojo. Yo estoy trabajando con varios `tags` como `font`, `small`, `<br />` ... etc. y en los colores mismos, una vez puede ser rojo, otra verde, otra negro... Lo que busco es algo sencillo para poder poner cualquier texto entre dos tags cualesquiera predefinidos.

Comment: pues reemplaza el color estatico y los pasas como parametro...

Comment: @Tegito123 aún así, la función sólo serviría para `font color`, pero no para `small`, `<br />` y otros tags.

Comment: me parece que seria bueno continuar x chat..!!

Comment: también podes usar un builder https://packagist.org/packages/avplab/php-html-builder

Answer (score 3):

Podes usar 'sprintf' onda:

```
<?php

$cssColor="<font color=\"%s\">%s</font>";

$cssSmall="<small>%s</small>";
$cssStrong="<strong>%s</strong>";

$texto = "Lorem Ipsum";

$tSm = sprintf($cssSmall, $texto);
$tSt = sprintf($cssStrong, $texto);

$tStSm = sprintf($cssStrong, $tSm);
$tSmSt = sprintf($cssSmall, $tSt);

$tCr = sprintf($cssColor, 'red', $texto);
$tCb = sprintf($cssColor, 'blue', $texto);

$tCbSm = sprintf($cssSmall, $tCb);

echo "small ".$tSm.PHP_EOL;
echo "strong ".$tSt.PHP_EOL;
echo "small strong ".$tSmSt.PHP_EOL;
echo "strong small".$tStSm.PHP_EOL;
echo "red ".$tCr.PHP_EOL;
echo "blue ".$tCbSm.PHP_EOL;
echo "blue small ".$tCbSm.PHP_EOL;
```

resultado:

```
small <small>Lorem Ipsum</small>
strong <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>
small strong <small><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong></small>
strong small<strong><small>Lorem Ipsum</small></strong>
red <font color="red">Lorem Ipsum</font>
blue <small><font color="blue">Lorem Ipsum</font></small>
blue small <small><font color="blue">Lorem Ipsum</font></small>
```

Answer (score 1):

Porque no simplificar todo con un método y/o función de la siguiente manera:

```
function makeHTML($tag, $content){
    echo "<$tag>$content</$tag>";
}

makeHTML("h1", "Title");
```

Lo anterior simplemente tendría como resultado:

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
```

Y si quieres hacer uso de los atributos, sería sencillo con un arreglo

```
function makeHTML($tag = "div", $attributes = [], $content){

    $attrs = "";

    foreach($attributes as $key => $value){
        $attrs .= $key."='".$value."' ";
    }

    echo "<$tag $attrs>$content</$tag>";
}

makeHTML("font", ['color' => 'red', 'data' => 'none'], "Soy una fuente de color rojo");
```

Resultado:

```html
<font color='red' data='none'>Soy una fuente de color rojo</font>
```

Actualización

Si es por que el `TextView` en Android no lee reglas de css en el atributo `style` porque no heredarle los atributos a un elemento hijo que siempre sea font y reciba el `$content`

```
function makeHTML($tag = "div", $attributes = [], $content){

   $attrs = "";

   foreach($attributes as $key => $value){
       $attrs .= $key."='".$value."' ";
   }

    echo "<$tag><font $attrs>$content</font></$tag>";
}

makeHTML("h1", ['color' => 'red'], "Soy un título de color rojo");
```

El resultado simplemente sería:

```html
<h1><font color="red">Soy una fuente de color rojo</font></h1>
```

Comment: Estoy por quedarme con tu versión, un poco mejorada: `function makeHTML($tag, $content, $attr = []){
    $str="<$tag";
    if($attr){
        foreach($attr as $k => $v){
            $str .= ' '.$k.'="'.$v.'"';
        }
    }
    $str.=">$content</$tag>";
    return $str;
}`  pero hay un caso en el que se me cae. Necesito algunos encabezados con color, por ejemplo: `<h3><font color="red">Lorem ipsum</font></h3>` ... ¿alguna idea para adaptar la función a esos casos?

Comment: @A.Cedano tiene que ser con una etiqueta `<font>` porque con el argumento `attributes` puedes pasarle lo siguiente y funcionaria a la perfección `'style' => 'color:red;'`

Comment: Voy a probar si me lo toma así en la App. El problema, como expliqué en el planteamiento es que la App tiene un `TextView` con un spanned que no admite reglas de estilo CSS, solamente le puedo pasar colores dentro de los elementos. De todos modos pruebo y ahora te comento.

Comment: @A.Cedano solo sería para las etiquetas hN?

Comment: o tienes que aplicarle un font a cualquier otra etiqueta para poder aplicarle el color directamente desde el atributo?

Comment: Efectivamente, no me lo permite debido a que es un `span` limitado en la App el cual no admite reglas de estilo CSS. La cosa es que no quiero lanzar una actualización de la App solamente por eso, así que trato de resolver el problema de otro modo, temporalmente. Si yo quiero aplicar color a cualquier texto tengo que poner el texto dentro de `<font color="color">Texto</font>`. Una solución en el caso de los `h` sería pasar la cadena así por ejemplo: `$strHTML.="<h3>".$this->makeHTML("font", "lectura breve",['color' => 'red'])."</h3>";`, con las etiquetas `h` fuera.  Así sí funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Sin duda me agrado tu problema, una posible solucion seria usar un switch.

Donde valides para caso como font, p, li, etc...
te dejo el codigo y captura de output

```
<?php
function texto_con_color($tipo, $custom_color, $texto){

    switch ($tipo) {

    case 'font':

            $color=$custom_color;
            $cssFont_="<font color=\"$color\">";
            $_cssFont='</font>';
            $mi_textofinal = $cssFont_ .$texto.$_cssFont;
        break;

    case 'small':

        $cssSmall_="<small>";
        $_cssSmall="</small>";
        $mi_textofinal = $cssSmall_.$texto.$_cssSmall;
        break;
    case 'p':
        $cssPar_="<p>";
        $_cssPar="</p>";
        $mi_textofinal = $cssPar_.$texto.$_cssPar;
        break;
    }

    return $mi_textofinal;

}
echo htmlspecialchars(texto_con_color('p', '', 'prueba de texto'));
?>
```

**Output**

[image: OutPut]

Si deseas llamar a font seria algo asi:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(texto_con_color('font', 'green', 'prueba de texto'));
```

Como notaras pasas el tipo(font), color(green), text(prueba de texto).

**Y el output:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y asi puedes ir creando y adaptando a tus necesidades..!!

Answer (score 0):

Propongo una función que acabo de hacer, no estoy seguro que sea lo que buscas pero puede ayudar hasta cierto punto:

```
<?php

function convert($text,$array){
    for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
        $bool=strpos($text,"{".$i."}");
        if($bool!=false){
            $text = str_ireplace("{".$i."}", $array[$i], $text);
        }
    }
    return $text;
}

$color1="red";
$color2="green";
$text=convert("<small> {0} </small><br> <center><font color='{1}'> texto rojo </font> {2}</center>",["texo sin importancia en small",$color1," al lado del texto rojo y centrado"]);
echo $text;
$text=convert("<small> {0} </small><br> <center><font color='{1}'> texto verde </font> {2}</center>",["texo sin importancia en small",$color2," al lado del texto verde y centrado"]);
echo $text;
```

El resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dicha función recibe un texto con caracteres `{} (llaves)` y en su interior el numero/posición del **array contenedor de los valores a reemplazar**. Dicho procedimiento es similiar/igual a la de `C#`.

Un Ejemplo mas complicado seria

```
$text=convert("<{0}> {1} </{0}><{5}> <{2} color='{3}'> {4} </{2}>",["small","texto en small","font","blue","texto azul","br"]);
echo $text;
```

Su resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]